# My LWJGL Game Introduction state video?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I want to play a video in my LWJGL game for an introduction. How could I do that ?

I already have set up multiple states now I am just trying to implement the introduction video in the already created state.

```
//This for now keeps the into state the red color for now. 
public void introElement(){

    //This clears the color from the previous State.
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //This changes the color to red.
    GL11.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to be too harsh on you but that was quite funny :p

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've found this already, but it looks like there is a library called [gdx-video](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-video) that might suit your needs. Take a look at [VideoPlayerDesktop.java](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-video/blob/master/gdx-video-desktop/src/com/badlogic/gdx/video/VideoPlayerDesktop.java), which appears to have several self-explanatory methods to play a video (`play()`, `pause()`, `render()`, etc.) The library is still being actively developed, although it looks like it may have several bugs.

If you'd rather have more control over the video, there is another plain Java library called [xuggle](http://xuggle.com); however it appears to be very old (no longer has support).

Finally, I found [someone's implementation](https://github.com/pirelenito/MovieGL) of a Java program that uses OpenGL to render a video. Although it is not a library, you could use it as a reference to help you develop your own program.

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested, the concept behind is that you stream a texture to the GPU, (the link shows the _wrong_ way of doing it). Put simply, you have two (or more) textures that you upload the data and render respectively: 1. Upload frame to tex1, Draw tex2  2. Upload to tex2, Draw tex1  3. Repeat